# How to .getUserMedia() from server as peer

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webrtc, video-capture

I am serving a webpage using express in node that I intend to access publicly (not worried about security yet) using DDNS.

I successfully configured WebRTC to getUserMedia - the problem is that, naturally, it looks for the media on the client side (the browser accessing the public server). Is there any way to getUserMedia from the server side?

Here is my code currently:

```
video = document.getElementById('video');

const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const audioSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');
const videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');

powerButton = document.getElementById('power');
icon = document.getElementById('loading');

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(gotDevices).then(getStream).catch(handleError);

audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    const deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;

    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'microphone ' +
        (audioSelect.length);
      audioSelect.appendChild(option);
    }

    else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'camera ' +
        (videoSelect.length);
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    }

    else {
      console.log('Found another kind of device: ', deviceInfo);
    }
  }
}

function getStream() {
  if (window.stream) {
    window.stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
      track.stop();
    });
  }

  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      deviceId: {exact: audioSelect.value}
    },
    video: {
      deviceId: {exact: videoSelect.value},
      width: {min: 1280},
      height: {min: 720}
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
    then(gotStream).catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  window.stream = stream;
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error('Error: ', error);
}
```

Comment: To show what? The guy sweeping the floor at the data-center?

Comment: Haha Actually a capture card - WebRTC picks it up nicely on when client is this server

Comment: I'd say don't go the webAPI way. Why does it need to be using webRTC? You may have success using something like [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/), which could convert whatever convenient video stream from your server to an RTC stream, but in your position, I would have a look at solutions like GStreamer and alike to stream the video directly.